# Git: commits still get labeled with a dead account

Tags: git, github, account

This is not a huge problem for me, but kinda embarrassing. Years ago I used two different GitHub accounts. One my very own `(1)`, another for some technical purposes `(2)` (to work by invitation, probably; don't ask for details, I cant remember). They got different nicknames and passwords, one can log in properly and separately.

I work exclusively under `(1)`, but all my commits are labeled as if I used `(2)`. Probably, `(2)` has nothing to do with it; I deleted it, but it still lives posthumously in my new commits. It does not matter much for me, since I work alone; still, it does not look nice.

How am I supposed to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github link commits to authors by looking at author/committer emails in the commit. Verify your global (per-user) and local (per-repository) settings `user.name` and `user.email`:

```
git config [--global] user.name
git config [--global] user.email
```

In your github account verify that you listed all necessary emails.

Comment: Than you very much!

Comment: Good answer, but won't this only affect new commits and not old ones?

Comment: Changing authorship for existing commits is certainly [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750182/7976758) but not recommended — it means changing history and requires force-push.